# Objective-C overriding _Nullable parameter with _Nonnull parameter

Tags: objective-c

Why this code generates the following warning?

```
@interface Foo : NSObject 
- (void)m:(id _Nullable)p;
@end

@interface Bar : Foo
- (void)m:(id _Nonnull)p;
@end
```

conflicting nullability specifier on parameter types, '_Nonnull' conflicts with existing specifier '_Nullable' [-Wnullability]

But the other way does not generate warnings:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject 
- (void)m:(id _Nonnull)p;
@end

@interface Bar : Foo
- (void)m:(id _Nullable)p;
@end
```

Is it because in the second case we going from more restrictive to less restrictive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's all because of **[Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)**

According to this principle:

> if S is a subtype of T, then objects of
>   type T may be replaced with objects of type S without altering any of
>   the desirable properties of the program.

---

In your example: `Bar` is subtype of `Foo`. So you should be able to replace instance of `Foo` with instance of `Bar`.

In other words, imagine method

```
- (void)doSomethingWith:(Foo *)object {
    [object m:nil];
}
```

If you pass to this method instance of `Foo` - everything is ok. But you may not pass to it instance of `Bar` - because you may not call `[Bar m:nil]`

Here you can see, that this code breaks Liskov substitution principle.

---

Otherwise, in the second example, everything is fine.

Imagine method:

```
- (void)doSomethingWith:(Foo *)object {
    [object m:@""]; // _Nonnull requirement
}
```

As you can see, you can pass to this method instances of both `Foo` and `Bar` classes.

---

**NOTE:** Here it is important to note that in Objc (unlike Swift) these rules are not so strict and you can easily deceive the compiler.

Comment: It's also important to note that the principle is strongly related to behavior, meaning that the compiler will not always catch such violations. For instance, the example about the Rectangle and Square can still happen.